# Allow multiple file upload in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In a webpage there is an input field that allows a user to select a file to upload. The relevant code is

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="versionFile" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
```

How would I use Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey to change the code to the following to allow multiple file uploads

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="versionFile" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" multiple>
```

Comment: I have spotted a flaw in your plan; the server will need to be programmed to accept multiple files, too

Comment: I modified the code using Chrome debugging (just added 'multiple' to the input tag) and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the server will accept multiple file uploads, all you need to do is select the input element after it exists and add a *multiple* attribute;

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('fileupload').setAttribute('multiple', '');
});
```

I'm assuming this code is being executed before the page has finished loading. If it's after then you shouldn't wrap it in a load handler.

---

- [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: The `window.addEventListener` is causing issues. If I just run the setAttribute it works fine but the addEventListener is never run. I added a console.log inside and it never ran. Any recommendations on how to get it to load?

Comment: I was able to have it work by running `setTimeout(function(){if(document.getElementById('fileupload')) document.getElementById('fileupload').setAttribute('multiple', '');}, 3000);`. Not the best solution but if you have one that works better, please let me know.